# Convert datetime to local datetime Winrt

Tags: c#, datetime, windows-runtime

I have a datetime object that is in `EST`, I need to convert that to the timezone the user is in.

I tried doing this

```
i.incDate.ToUniversalTime().ToLocalTime();
```

but that does not give me anything close to the right time. I have seen plenty of examples using `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById` but this does not exist in `Winrt`

so what is the proper way to convert timezones in winrt?

Comment: What is the `Kind` of `i.incDate`?

Comment: @SonerGönül its says unspecified

Comment: Do you *know* the time zone of the user already, or not? And is the original value *really* in EST, or is it in Eastern Time? (EST is always UTC-5, assuming you mean the US Eastern Standard Time... Eastern Time comprises EST and EDT.)

Comment: You can't have a DateTime in a specific timezone, it's either local, universal or unknown (unspecified). Your code should return the original datetime. You should use at least DateTimeOffset to include an offset if you want to work with multiple timezones

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: It's local, universal or unspecified, as far as DateTime.Kind is concerned...

Comment: @JonSkeet I know, I was editing the comment as I went.

Comment: @JonSkeet I can get the TimeZone with using `TimeZoneInfo.Local` if thats what you mean but it needs to handle any timezone. Yes dates ate UTC-5/4 depending on DST

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: But it's at least *somewhat* reasonable to have a `DateTime` value with a `Kind` of unspecified, but know what the original time zone was. That's fine for most cases, although it can be ambiguous in some cases. Using a `DateTimeOffset` would be preferable, but *may* not be feasible.

Comment: @tyczj: What do you mean by "it needs to handle any time zone"? Do you mean any local one, or any one specified somewhere else?

Comment: @JonSkeet any `Local` zone. all EST dates should be converted to their equivalent local time

Comment: Wait a minute, [in WinRT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205768.aspx) DateTime is *not* available, DateTimeOffset is! What is the actual data type after all??? Just a call to [ToOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.tooffset(v=vs.110).aspx) should be enough to change the timezone to any other. An equivalent call is [TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396765(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos DateTime is certainly available in WinRT

Comment: According to the documentation I linked, the *keyword* is equivalent to DateTimeOffset. This means that your `indCate` has an `Offset` Property which should be -5h and the `ToOffset` method to convert it to another offset.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it does not have an `Offset` property, i can get one by doing `new DateTimeOffset(i.incDate);` though

Answer (score 0):

WinRT has a Calendar class with a ChangeTimeZone method. I suspect this can be used to do this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Windows.Globalization.Calendar.ChangeTimeZone